# Deleted Ubuntu partition. Now Windows nor Linux can start due to GRUB's normal.mod not found

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, grub, uefi, elementaryos

I had Windows 10 and ElementaryOS Freya (Ubuntu 14.04) installed and both booting happily through GRUB.

**This is how my disks were set up:**

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1 ntfs 420MB
/dev/sda2 ntfs 210GB - Windows 10 OS
/dev/sda3 ntfs 167GB - Windows 10 Storage
/dev/sda5 ext4 122GB - Freya

/dev/sdb - small little 24GB disk that my laptop uses normally for recovery, but I repurposed it for other uses
/dev/sdb1 swap 10GB
/dev/sdb2 ntfs 14GB
```

I wanted to remove Freya and upgrade to Loki (Ubuntu 16.04) so I booted into the Loki Live disk and used GParted to delete my Freya partition on `sda5`. I then had the Loki installer use `sda5` as the install location but at the end of installation it said:

```
Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed.
This is a fatal error.
```

Now when I try booting I get `file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.` at boot.

**So in `grub rescue` I try:**

```
set root=(hd0,msdos5)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
insmod normal
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
```

This doesn't work because `msdos5` was formatted.

**So I make a Windows 10 Recovery Disk and boot from it.**

I use Startup Repair but that fails - `Startup Repair couldn't repair your PC.`

I then use Command Prompt (note what it says up top about low memory):

```
Microsoft Windows (Version 10.0.17134.1)
Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

X:\windows\system32>BOOTREC /FIXMBR
The operation completed successfully.

X:\windows\system32>BOOTREC /REBUILDBCD
Scanning all disks...
Total identified Windows installations: 1
[1] D:\Windows
Add installation to boot list? Y
The requested system device cannot be found

X:\windows\system32>BOOTREC /FIXBOOT
Access is denied.
```

**Anything else?**

Guh, I've been at this for hours now. Should I do what user BillyBigun says to do here? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-bootrec-fixboot-access-is-denied/747c4180-7ff3-4bc2-b6cc-81e572d546df

His instructions are basically to format the EFI partition... so basically format sda1 (420MB), right?

What else can I do?

Comment: Did you tried to reinstall grub using this method ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: Boot-repair worked. Man, it really should be integrated as part of the standard installation for ElementaryOS. Even installing EOS through its step-by-step installer made the system unbootable, necessitating the use of grub-repair, which wasn't a straightforward installation either.